# Fastest/safest way to redirect from static HTML site to Wordpress (new domain, with some permalink structure changes)

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

Could somebody explain the safest and fastest (performance wise) way to perform 34 redirects, with a mix of straight up domain swaps and also some permalink structure changes? The old site is static HTML and the new site is WP. So a few examples would be:

www.olddomain.com/index.html > www.newdomain.com

www.olddomain.com/about-us.html > www.newdomain.com/about

www.olddomain.com/oldcategory/page.html > www.newdomain.com/newcategory/page

www.olddomain.com/page2.html > www.newdomain.com/newcategory/page2

EDIT:

I should add that I did read a few articles before posting, this one seemed useful with options for plugins or using .htaccess...

https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/

...but it seemed to focus on Wp to Wp redirects, and I wasn't sure if there was a different procedure for doing static to WP redirects. I also read that the .htaccess method can be slow if there are a lot of redirects.

In any case I'll go ahead and try the first suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

you can add the following lines to your .htaccess file located at the root of **your old domain:** [More info](https://wpscholar.com/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

To redirect a single page to a new location on the same domain, use the following syntax:

```
Redirect 301 /old/old.htm https://www.example.com/new.htm

Redirect 301 /index.html > www.newdomain.com
Redirect 301 /about-us.html > www.newdomain.com/about
Redirect 301 /oldcategory/page.html > www.newdomain.com/newcategory/page
Redirect 301 /page2.html > www.newdomain.com/newcategory/page2
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a two step process - step 1 to redirect all traffic to the new domain (performed on the old domain .htacess file), and then step 2, manually redirect any changes to  link structure on the new domain .htacess file?

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess file would be fast and clean (put in the root of the HTML site).

Example:

```
Redirect 301 /old/file.html https://www.askapache.com/new/file/
```

See https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/#htaccess_Code_Snippets

Comment: So a single set of redirects on the old domain will take care it all, with no instruction needed on the new domian? This is what was confusing me - @ravipatel below mentions a two step process.